# Regex to match property in XML

Tags: regex, notepad++

Please help me. I need to find all log that contain `<field id="0" value="0200"/>` AND `<field id="24" value="001"/>`. I use this regex `<log.+?<field id="0" value="0200"/>.+?<field id="24" value="001"/>.+?</log>` using Notepad++, that does not work very well.

```
<log>
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="incoming">
      <header>6008610000</header>
      <field id="0" value="0200"/>
      <field id="3" value="440000"/>
      <field id="11" value="000001"/>
      <field id="24" value="001"/>
      <field id="41" value="12345678"/>
      <field id="42" value="0000012345678"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
<log>
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="incoming">
      <header>6008610000</header>
      <field id="0" value="0300"/>
      <field id="3" value="440000"/>
      <field id="11" value="000002"/>
      <field id="24" value="002"/>
      <field id="41" value="12345678"/>
      <field id="42" value="0000012345678"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
<log>
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="incoming">
      <header>6008610000</header>
      <field id="0" value="0200"/>
      <field id="3" value="440000"/>
      <field id="11" value="000002"/>
      <field id="24" value="001"/>
      <field id="41" value="12345678"/>
      <field id="42" value="0000012345678"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
<log>
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="incoming">
      <header>6008610000</header>
      <field id="0" value="0200"/>
      <field id="3" value="440000"/>
      <field id="11" value="000002"/>
      <field id="24" value="004"/>
      <field id="41" value="12345678"/>
      <field id="42" value="0000012345678"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
```

Comment: It's bad juju to regex match XML. It doesn't work very well, because XML is a contextual thing, where regex isn't. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you should use some XML parser for this purpose.

If you really want to do this with regex, you need to note:

- `.+` wildcard does not match new line character. Try `[\s\S]+` instead,
- acceptable fields might appear in random order,
- your regex shouldn't match more than one `<log></log>` block.

Edit:

If regex is the only option, and you just want to find all occurrances of mentioned fields, you can try some ugly regex, like

```
((<field id="0" value="0200".*)\s*((<field.*)*\s*)*?(<field id="24" value="001".*))+?|((<field id="24" value="001".*)\s*((<field.*)*\s*)*?(<field id="0" value="0200".*))+?`
```

which means: match text that starts with `<field id="0" value="0200"`, than having only `<field.*` lines, ending with `<field id="24" value="001".*` or starts with `<field id="24" value="001".*` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ does not support multiline regex.

Comment: This is not an answer.